# sliding up down DIV on click with more categories

Tags: javascript, html, click, categories, sliding

I have very little understanding of javascripting so i would really appreciate it if someone helps me out

i would like this effect http://jsfiddle.net/dJS4g/ but instead of one link i would like to have 6 links that will show different content on click

```
javascript
$(function()
  {
     $("a#toggle").click(function()
                         {
                            $("#contact").slideToggle();
                            return false;
                         }); 
  });

html
<div id="contact">
    Contact me!
</div>
<a href="#" id="toggle">Contact</a>

css
#contact
{
    display: none;
    background: grey;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**

> FOUND WHAT I WAS LOOKING FOR HERE
>   http://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/XwN2L/2154/ THANK YOU EVERYONE FOR YOUR
>   HELP

**

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MaxMarkson/dJS4g/154/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#all").click(function () {
        $("#newborn").slideToggle();
        $("#family").slideToggle();
        $("#senior").slideToggle();
        $("#portrait").slideToggle();
        $("#wedding").slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

In this way by clicking on the first div, the others are shown. Clicking again the others divs disappear.

Pay attention: don't set the `slideToggle()` even to the `#all` div because otherwise you can't toggle the other divs anymore

Answer (score 0):

you can check below both `jsfiddle` file. it's working fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/UpuDU/  [ Accordion Type ]

http://jsfiddle.net/UpuDU/6/  [ Tab Type ]

Comment: thats kind of what i want but not... i want the links to be inline and the drop up and down effect to happen under them

Comment: do you want like submenu?